# How to output a 32 floating value in a render buffer with fragment shader

Tags: shader, 3d, glsl, depth-map

I would like to downsample my depth buffer and my normals.
For that, I take in input of my shader, the corresponding textures (depth, normal), and I write my new values in a multi render target.

I downsample the normals by doing a simple average of four texels and for the depth buffer, I can choose the max or min of four texels.

My color attachment's format for the downsampled buffer is R32F.
How could I write my new depth floating point value in it?
I tried: `gl_FragData[1].r = newDepth;` 
But it doesn't seem to store correctly a float with 32 bits precision.

To get a pixel's depth, I know that I can do:
`float depth = texture2D(depth, tc).x;`
But what about to output a single float with 32 bits precision?

Comment: Why do you think it does not store correctly? Does your `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` is also 32 bit float type?